# Properly resize GridLayout in a PartView

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an Image in a grid that scales when the PartView is resized. If the BarsView starts smaller than 64 high (the size of the canvas), the bottom portion of the image gets cut off below the initial size. If it starts larger than what it is resized to, the minivitals does not shrink as it should. How can I the layout, when resized, to look like it does when I open the program at that size?

Screenshot of when the program is opened at normal size:

[image: Normal size to start]

Shrunk after opening at normal size (notice the concentration bar is pushed off the bottom of the screen):

[image]

Opened at smaller size:

[image]

Opened at smaller size then expanded:

[image]

Restarting between resizing has the desired effect, except for the needing to restart part.

```
public class BarsView extends ViewPart {
    private PageBook book;
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {   
        book = new PageBook(parent, SWT.NONE);
        book.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        Composite page = new BarsPageView(book, view);
        book.showPage(page);
    }
    private class BarsPageView extends Composite {
        public BarsPageView(Composite parent, GameView view) {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

        // This is a wrapper around a StyledText
        entry = new StormFrontEntry(this, view);
        GridData entryData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false);
        entryData.heightHint = 22;
        entry.getWidget().setLayoutData(entryData); // getWidget() returns the StyledText

        // This is a Composite containing a Canvas
        status = new StormFrontStatus(this, view);
        status.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.BEGINNING, false, false));

        // This is defined below                
        GridData compassData = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 2);
        compassData.heightHint = 64;
        compass = new WarlockCompass(this, SWT.NONE, theme, compassData);
        compass.setLayoutData(compassData);

        minivitals = new StormFrontDialogControl(this, SWT.NONE);
        GridData mvData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1);
        minivitals.setLayoutData(mvData);
    }
}

public class WarlockCompass extends Canvas {
    public WarlockCompass (final Composite parent, int style, CompassTheme theme, GridData layoutData) {
        super(parent, style);
        addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                drawCompass(e.gc);
            }
        });
        parent.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                // I cut out the calculations for this
                layoutData.heightHint = height;
                WarlockCompass.this.setSize(width, height);
            }
        });
    }
    private void drawCompass (GC gc) {
        // Cut out the calculations to scale the image to fix the canvas
        gc.drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // This is defined below                
    GridData compassData = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 2);
    compassData.heightHint = 64;
    compass = new WarlockCompass(this, SWT.NONE, theme, compassData);
    compass.setLayoutData(compassData);
```

Should have been:

```
    // This is defined below                
    GridData compassData = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, true, 1, 2);
    compassData.heightHint = 64;
    compass = new WarlockCompass(this, SWT.NONE, theme, compassData);
    compass.setLayoutData(compassData);
```

Changing that flag makes it resize properly.